# How can implement bootstrap form class in react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to React.js. I am trying to create a form in React using React Bootstrap but I don't know why the form=control CSS is not implemented. I inspect the code in the browser and the form-control class is implemented on the div but the right side CSS properties are now shown and the input field style is also not changed.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import './sign-up.css'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

export class SignUp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="position-relative">
        <div className="split left">
          <Form className="mx-auto px-5">
            <div className="  row">
              <div>
                <Form.Label for='first_name'>First Name</Form.Label><br/>
                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter First name" />
              </div>

              <div>
                <Form.Label for='last_name'>Last Name</Form.Label><br/>
                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter last name" />
              </div>
            </div>
        
            <label for='email'>Email</label><br/>
            <input type='email' placeholder='Enter your email name' id='email'/>
        
            <label for='password'>Password</label><br/>
            <input type='password' placeholder='Enter your password name' id='password'/>
        
            <label for='phone'>Phone Number</label><br/>
            <input type='tel' placeholder='Enter your phone number' id='phone'/>
           <button type='Submit'> Submit</button>
        </Form>
     </div>
     <div className="split right">
       
     </div>
    </div>
 );
}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install bootstrap package

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

then add this line in your component

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```